# How do I update Spinners in a MainActivity when clicking either the ToolBar back arrow or phone Back button?

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-toolbar, back-button

**Problem:**

How would I refresh `Spinner` data in a `MainActivity` through the use of the `ToolBar` back arrow or phone "back button?"

**What I am trying to do (would like to do):**

Right now, clicking the toolbar back arrow or back button just takes me back to the MainActiity previous state... which is expected behavior without any activity updates. What I wanted to do was trigger some updates to the `Spinners` in the `MainActivity`.

**How the app spinners function (High-Level):**

In my MainActivity are two `Spinners` called **Topic** and **Question** used to return results on the choices made and the user clicks on the results returned to take them to other activities. In later activities, the list data used in the spinners may have been updated or changed. For example, a Topic may have been added or removed. So, when the user eventually returns to the `MainActivity`, I would like for that list to be updated.

**What I have done:**

My thought was I would need to use the toolbar arrow or phone back button `OnClick` with an `Intent`. Truthfully, both the arrow and button have to function the same in this respect. Unless someone thought there was a better solution, which I'm open to, this was my solution for updating the spinners in the main activity. I was struggling to find how this may be done with the ToolBar arrow and the Back Button.... and whether that was the right solution. I would like to avoid creating a menu button to do the same if I can use the arrow and back buttons.

Below are 3 images demonstrating how this works. Image 1, the user chose a Question to return a result. Image 2 is the result with the Question edited. In image 3, the Main Activity spinner retains the old list and value and there is no result because the question was changed and there is nothing to return for this question value now.

**Question choice and result**

[image: Image 1]

**Question was edited by user**

[image: Image 2]

**Old question list value remains - there's no result due to the change**

[image: Image 3]

Comment: Please have a review of this [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)

Comment: @Muhammad Zahab Ahmad Khan - Thanks this is perfect!